# Typescript: Is there a way to disable all syntactical checks for test files?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm running a fairly large Angular enterprise application with a few thousand unit tests, we use custom webpack configurations tailored to our project and now I want to update our test tools to keep them in line with our version of Angular.

Currently our unit tests are set up using `ts-loader` and `angular2-template-loader` and the spec files are compiled seemingly without syntax checks which I think is fine for test files - we want to use minimal mocks for the tests without having to use partials or other workarounds.

Now I'm trying to replace the aforementioned loaders with `@angular-devkit` and standard `karma` and `tsconfig` files.

However, now I can't run our test suite without getting hundreds of errors because of type mismatches or other syntactical mistakes.

While these these errors are technically true, they are also irrelevant to the execution of the tests themselves.

Since `ts-loader` was able compile and run the spec files on the exact same version of Typescript without throwing these errors it must be possible to do this also with `@angular-devkit`, maybe by disabling type checks for files matching a certain pattern?